# survfit() Shade 95% confidence interval survival plot

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Im not sure... this cant be that difficult i think, but i cant work it out. If you run:

```
library(survival)    
leukemia.surv <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = aml) 
plot(leukemia.surv, lty = 2:3)
```

you see the survival curve and its 95% confidence interval. Instead of showing two lines that show the upper and lower 95% CI, id like to shade the area between the upper and lower 95% boundries.

Does this have to be done by something like polygon()? All coordinates can be found in the summary...

```
> summary(leukemia.surv)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = aml)

 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
5     23       2   0.9130  0.0588       0.8049        1.000
8     21       2   0.8261  0.0790       0.6848        0.996
9     19       1   0.7826  0.0860       0.6310        0.971
12     18       1   0.7391  0.0916       0.5798        0.942
13     17       1   0.6957  0.0959       0.5309        0.912
18     14       1   0.6460  0.1011       0.4753        0.878
23     13       2   0.5466  0.1073       0.3721        0.803
27     11       1   0.4969  0.1084       0.3240        0.762
30      9       1   0.4417  0.1095       0.2717        0.718
31      8       1   0.3865  0.1089       0.2225        0.671
33      7       1   0.3313  0.1064       0.1765        0.622
34      6       1   0.2761  0.1020       0.1338        0.569
43      5       1   0.2208  0.0954       0.0947        0.515
45      4       1   0.1656  0.0860       0.0598        0.458
48      2       1   0.0828  0.0727       0.0148        0.462
```

Is there an existing function to shade the 95% CI area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use data from the `summary()` to make your own plot with the confidence interval as polygon.

First, save the `summary()` as an object. Data for plotting are located in variables `time`, `surv`, `upper` and `lower`.

```
mod<-summary(leukemia.surv)
```

Now you can use function `plot()` to define the plotting region. Then with `polygon()` plot confidence interval. Here you have to provide x values and x values in reverse order, and for y values use `lower` values and revere `upper` values. With function `lines()` add survival line. By adding argument `type="s"` to `lines()` you will get line as steps.

```
with(mod,plot(time,surv,type="n",xlim=c(5,50),ylim=c(0,1)))
with(mod,polygon(c(time,rev(time)),c(lower,rev(upper)),
                 col = "grey75", border = FALSE))
with(mod,lines(time,surv,type="s"))
```

Comment: is it easy to change this so i can actually see the steps? including the marks for censored data?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a function to plot shaded confidence intervals in survival curves. You can find it here: [Plotting survival curves in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921457/plotting-survival-curves-in-r-with-ggplot2)

Maybe you can find it useful.